# MRI Internals: detailed explanation of rb_id2str

Tags: ruby

In MRI, it appears that `rb_id2str()` is responsible for doing all of the work when you call `Symbol#to_s`. I was surprised to discover this is an extremely cryptic function for something that I assumed would be a fairly straight forward operation.

I'm looking for a detailed explanation of what this function is doing. For reference, here is a link to the source in 1.9.3:

http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/parse.y?v=1.9.3-p195#9950

Some specific questions:

What are the four major `if` blocks doing?

1. `if (id < tLAST_TOKEN)`
2. `if (id < INT_MAX && rb_ispunct((int)id))`
3. `if (st_lookup(global_symbols.id_str, id, &data))`
4. `if (is_attrset_id(id))`

It would be great to get a generic overview of what each block of code inside the if statements does, but it doesn't need to be a line-by-line analysis.

Finally, I'm curious about the memory/garbage collection implications of `to_s`: does calling `Symbol#to_s` create a new string that has to be garbage collected every time, or is there something like internal copy-on-write optimization that uses a reference to the interned representation of the symbol up until a mutation is made to the string?

Comment: `rb_id2str` does a lot more than just that. `Symbol#to_s` is actually equivalent to `rb_sym_to_s`. That function gets the object's ID using `SYM2ID` and only then it calls `rb_id2str` with the ID returned by `SYM2ID` as the parameter to construct a string from the object's ID. There might be some steps that I missed, though. I am sure about the memory usage related to `to_s`, but I would guess (and hope) it doesn't create a new string

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, I'm pretty sure Symbol#to_s creates a new string. 
Most ruby classes are C structs, except for TrueClass, FalseClass, NilClass, Fixnum and Symbol, which are int in C. So Symbol is a whole different story with String(That's why Symbol is recommended unless you need to change the value a lot).

I'm not sure if you know about the book Ruby Hacking Guide, it explains a lot about how MRI is implemented in C.

FYI, Ruby Hacking Guide is written in Japanese, and till now there's still only a small part is translated, looks like guys have given up on it. http://rhg.rubyforge.org/